# Is this the correct way to add elements to a container?

Tags: c++, opencv, stl

It's been a while since I've written C++, so I'd like to confirm I'm doing this correctly:

```
vector<Mat>
VideoHash::dct3d(vector<Mat> cube)
{
    vector<Mat> dctPlanes;
    for (int k = 0; k < TEMPORAL_DIM; ++k)
    {
        Mat spatial;
        Mat freq;
        cube[k].convertTo(spatial, CV_64F);
        dct(spatial, freq);
        dctPlanes.push_back(freq);
    }

    // Do other stuff here
}
```

I've got a vector of matrices as inputs to the function. For each matrix in the vector, I convert to a different data type (double), perform a DCT on the conversion result, and then store the result of the DCT in another vector.

Does this seem right? I'm having doubts about the matrices that are being created inside the for loop. They will go out of scope after the loop exits. What happens to the memory allocated to those matrices on the stack? Will that memory still be accessible after the loop (e.g. in the "do other stuff here" section).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you push_back a matrix into your vector, it's copied by value into memory that has been allocated by the vector.  As long as dctPlanes exists, the matrices in it will still exist.  Your temporaries (spatial, freq) will go out of scope every loop iteration of course.

Edit: To address optimization concerns, you may think about something like this:

```
VideoHash::dct3d(vector<Mat> & cube)
{
    Mat spatial;
    vector<Mat> dctPlanes;
    dctPlanes.resize(TEMPORAL_DIM);
    for (int k = 0; k < TEMPORAL_DIM; ++k)
    {
        cube[k].convertTo(spatial, CV_64F);
        dct(spatial, dctPlanes[k]);
    }

    // Do other stuff here
}
```

It's not perfect, since ideally you'd want avoid the cost of calling all of those constructors when you resize the vector - and there are ways around that - but this will get you decent gains compared to the original code.

Answer (score 0):

The `dctPlanes.push_back(freq)` will *copy* the temporary matrix `freq` into the container. If `Mat` has a correct copy constructor, you can still access the data through the container. Obviously, the `freq` and `spatial` themselves get destroyed at the end of the each iteration and cannot be accessed directly.

If efficiency is a concern, you may want to consider implementing a C++11 move constructor for Mat, and then using:

`dctPlanes.push_back( std::move(freq) )`

After this line, `freq` itself is invalidated even before the end of the loop scope - as it has been *moved* into the container.

Comment: I just wanted to add something regarding the performance concerns.  A move constructor will only improve performance if the Mat class is dynamically allocating memory.  I can't remember seeing a matrix class that does this, so it may be misleading to say this will improve performance.  In the case of a matrix class, there is usually no meaningful way to implement a move constructor.

Comment: If a matrix is of arbitrary dimension, you usually have a `size` field and a pointer to a dynamically allocated content of the matrix. A move constructor would then do a shallow swap. In this particular case I actually expect that it is the case, because DCT is usually done on big matrices (eg. images)

Comment: Ah, very good point.  I had totally read past the fact that was wasn't just simple matrices.  In that case it would definitely improve the performance.